# Удалить начало текста до второй запятой включительно

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Из базы достаю такую строку и она отображается в екселе `Горнообогатительное производство,Дробильно-обжиговый цех,Обжиговый участок,Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник № 6,Вращающаяся печь №4 Вход в циклон 1` 
Как обрезать слева слова разделенные запятой, чтобы осталось так.

```
Обжиговый участок,Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник № 6,Вращающаяся печь №4 Вход в циклон 1
```

Слова слева могут быть любые, главный разделитель это запятая.

Comment: Опять Вы неполно задачу описываете. По какому принципу обрезать?

Comment: Запятых-то хренова гора - за какую хвататься? Где вменяемый критерий, что брать и что выбрасывать?

Comment: @vikttur принцип простой, строка формируется эта из базы и собственно  каждое поле отделяется запятой, в примере ,что я привел получается так, [производство],[цех],[участок], и так далее. В моем случае получается [Горнообогатительное производство],[Дробильно-обжиговый цех],[Обжиговый участок]. Удалить нужно первые два поля. то есть [производство],[цех] и запятую, которая разграничивает [цех] и [участок]. Тогда в остатке получается строка Обжиговый участок,Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник № 6,Вращающаяся печь №4 Вход в циклон 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При поиске первого вхождения нужного символа просто:

```
=ПСТР(A4;ПОИСК(",";A4)+1;999)
```

Для того, чтобы найти следующие вхождения, нужно сначала заменить этот символ другим/несколькими, которого/которых гарантированно нет в тексте:

```
ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A4;",";"//";N)
```

где N - порядковый номер символа в тексте.

Ищем эту подмену и получаем результат:

```
=ПСТР(A4;ПОИСК("//";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A4;",";"//";2))+1;999)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, еще бы логику понять)

Comment: Добавил в ответ